# How to get event property again for already dragged image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have image that I want to drag and drop infinitely.From first box to second box when I move,image disappear from first box.Not to lose image created same image on first box again using .appendchild(img) method.I want to drag image from initial position,not from where I dropped.So I changed draggable property as false when I dropped image into box.It creates image on first box,there's no problem.But I can't drag and drop it from first box to third again because that image has no event properties.I want to give them those properties again and it should be repeated because I want to do it forever.
Here's what I tried

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1, #div2,#div3 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "https://mikasasports.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/MVA2001.png";
  var src = document.getElementById("div1");
  img.style.width="88px";
  img.style.height="31px";
  src.appendChild(img);
  drag1.draggable=false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<p>Drag the image back and forth between the three div elements.</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img src="https://mikasasports.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/MVA2001.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
</div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

</body>
</html>
```